# Testing POST request with Echo (expected vs actual output)

Tags: json, go, post, go-echo

I'm kinda new in Go, so, sorry if this is a silly question.

I have been recently trying some API with Echo. I'm trying to test a route(POST) handler of Go echo that gets a json and puts it in an array. Bellow is the code for the handler **main.go** and for the test **test_main.go**

`main.go`

```
type Houses struct {
Name    string `json:"name,ommitempty"`
Address string `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

var houses []Houses

func newHouse(c echo.Context) error {
    m := echo.Map{}
    if err := c.Bind(&m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    dv := Houses{
        Name:    m["name"].(string),
        Address: m["address"].(string),
    }
    houses = append(houses, dv)
    js, _ := json.Marshal(houses)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", js))

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, string(js))
}
```

`test_main.go`

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

var userJSON = `{"name":"Jhon Doe","address":"High St."}`

func TestModel(t *testing.T) {
    url := "/new_house"
    e := echo.New()
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url, strings.NewReader(userJSON))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("The request could not be created because of: %v", err)
    }
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
    // c.SetPath("/new_house")
    // c.JSON(http.StatusOK, Devices{"Jhon Doe", "Middle Way"})

    res := rec.Result()
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if assert.NoError(t, newHouse(c)) {
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
        assert.Equal(t, "["+userJSON+"]", rec.Body.String())
    }
}
```

The test fails with the error shown bellow even though the handler works properly if called by curl.

```
[{"name":"Jhon Doe","address":"High St."}]
--- FAIL: TestModel (0.00s)
    /home/gaidaros/Code/echo-badger/models/model_test.go:34: 
            Error Trace:    model_test.go:34
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: "[{\"name\":\"Jhon Doe\",\"address\":\"High St.\"}]"
                            actual  : "\"[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Jhon Doe\\\",\\\"address\\\":\\\"High St.\\\"}]\""

                            Diff:
                            --- Expected
                            +++ Actual
                            @@ -1 +1 @@
                            -[{"name":"Jhon Doe","address":"High St."}]
                            +"[{\"name\":\"Jhon Doe\",\"address\":\"High St.\"}]"
            Test:           TestModel
FAIL
exit status 1
```

After several days of struggling over it I couldn't figure out how to make the actual output to match the expected, so I'm posting here in hopes of getting past this obstacle. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `json.Marshal` on the `[]Houses`, which marshals it to a JSON string, then you are calling `echo.Context.JSON` with the JSON string, which internally calls `json.Marshal`. Double marshalling causes the escaping. See example. (error checking omitted for brevity)

https://play.golang.org/p/nYvHS4huy0M

```
h := &Houses{"Jhon Doe", "High St."}
d, _ := json.Marshal(h)

// double marshal bad
d, _ = json.Marshal(string(d))

fmt.Println(string(d))
// prints "{\"name\":\"Jhon Doe\",\"address\":\"High St.\"}"
```

Your solution is to just pass the slice to your `c.JSON` call. As a side note, you should be able to pass the struct to `c.Bind` instead of using a map with type assertions.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. I feel dumb right now. I'll be sure to keep your points in mind. Thanks!